# Set an array as parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parsing, element

I'm trying to parse an array from one function ton another.
I have seen in other posts that ".apply" can be used as in this example:

```
var x = [ 'p0', 'p1', 'p2' ]; 
call_me.apply(this, x);
```

But in my code I want to parse to other function not just one array, I want to parse the array and two strings more. So mi code looks more like:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var string = "something":
var string1 = "something":
ShowM(array, string, string2);

function ShowM(array, string1, string2) {
alert(array[1] + string1 + string2);
}
```

Is there any way to do that without changing the original location of the elements of the arrays for not getting undefined?. Thnks

Comment: So what is wrong with `apply`? It's not really clear what you are asking. What's `leftb`, `right` and `final` actually supposed to be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? Can you clarify please?

Comment: I just edited my post

Answer (score 1):

If the question is purely about how do you set an array as a parameter in Javascript as your topic question states, you just do like any other variable.

```
var array = [a,b,c];
var str = "hello";
var str2 = "something";

function foo(x,y,z) {
    // do stuff...
}

foo(array, str, str2); //executes function with the 3 parameters
```

Comment: But with this I get a different location for the array elements and usually prints "undefined"

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with what you're actually trying to do? I mean that as in give me an example with data and say what you want that data to end up as.

Comment: [Edited]I just want to get 1 in the function but it just show undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass the array into a function, you can pass it as you would any other variable:

```
function showM(a, b, c) {
    // empty function definition
}

var x = [ 'p0', 'p1', 'p2' ];
showM(x, "some string", "another string");
```

All arrays are passed by reference in javascript, so when you alter a passed array's contents within the function, the contents will change across all scopes. And duck-typing means that you can use any variable type as an argument.

The `apply` function, on the other hand, calls a function with a given content and an array of arguments (which it expands, like with the ES6 spread operator):

```
// equivalent to the other call, except "this" is bound to null
showM.apply(null, [x, "some string", "another string"]);
```

Comment: I'v tryed the two ones and everytime, the function put the element array[1] in array[3].

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, you need to spell out exactly the problem, including all the relevant code. But perhaps you want to pass the array by value rather than by reference. In which case, you can pass a [shallow] copy of the array by using the `slice` function like so: `showM(x.slice(), "a", "b");`

Comment: [Edited]I just want to get 1 in the function but it just show undefined.

Comment: Okay, I'm still struggling to understand, sorry. But you do know that arrays in javascript (and most programming languages) are zero-indexed? In other words, if you want to access the first value, you do `x[0]`, not `x[1]` (more generally, `x[x.length]` is always undefined in a densely populated array, and `x[x.length - 1]` refers to the last element, assuming that the array isn't empty, in which case that will be undefined too).